# Any plugins for Skype that support "Soundboard" usage?

Tags: audio, plugins, skype, voip

I would like to find a program or plugin for Skype that allows you to pipe sound samples in to the outgoing audio stream when you are on a call.  Ideally it would have some sort of soundboard functionality so that I could have a group of audio samples at the touch of a button.  I'd also prefer something that supports mp3 but wav support will also do.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I used skype the person I was calling could hear any sounds that played on my computer. Could have been a bug, an old version, or a peculiarity with my soundcard, but it might be worth giving it a try.

In fact, you can occasionally see this in action on the Stack Overflow podcast. Joel will get a notification from Outlook and you'll hear the "bing!" on the podcast

Comment: You sure he just doesn't have his speakers on and the mic is picking up the audio?

Answer (score 1):

A program like [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/), or possibly [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.html).

JACK works like a recording studio patch bay, allowing you to take audio input from one source or program and reroute it through other programs for processing before getting to audio hardware.  In this case, I think you'd want to insert stuff into the microphone signal before it gets to Skype.

I've never tried Virtual Audio Cable, but saw it recommended on another question and it sounds like it does basically the same thing as JACK.